# Vuejs2.6 - Images not loading

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I know there are several other questions about it, but none of them seems to help me.

I'm trying to create a simple Image component, but I images are not loading since I tried to use them in a component.

```
<template>
   <!-- <img :click="go()" :src="require(`../assets/img/${filename}`)"> -->
    <img :click="go()" :src="`../assets/img/'${filename}`"> 
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: 'Imagem',
    data() {
        return {
            filename: ''
        
        }
    },
    methods: {
        go() {
            console.log('image click')
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
img{
    min-width: 20%;
}
</style>
```

The first line throws error:
[image]

The second line, without require, gives no error but don't load the image (i restarted the project and cleaned cache)

[image]

This is the view where Imagem component is imported:

```
<template>
    <div class="login-images">
      <!-- <img @click="novoProfessor" src="../assets/professor.png" alt="" srcset="">
      <img @click="novoAluno" src="../assets/aluno.png" alt="" srcset=""> -->
      <Imagem :filename="'professor.png'" />
      <Imagem :filename="'aluno.png'" />

    </div>
</template>

<script>

import Imagem from '../components/Imagem';

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  components: {
    Imagem
  },
  props: {
    
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
.login-images {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center; 
}

.login-images > * {
  margin: 10%;
}



</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Imagem` component like this:

```html
<template>
  <img :src="imageURL" @click="go">
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default
{
  name: 'Imagem',
  props:
  {
    filename:
    {
      type: 'String',
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed:
  {
    imageURL()
    {
      return `../assets/img/${this.filename}`;
    }
  },
  methods:
  {
    go(event)
    {
      console.log('You clicked on the "' + event.target.src + '"');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, I had to change to type: String, or I get an error saying filename should be a constructor. But images are still not showing. Although in dev tools images have a 200 status, they appear like they were not in server, like my second image

Comment: You should check the MIME type which the images are being served with - if it is `text/html` or `text/plain` then the URL of the image is wrong. Try to put your images inside `public/img` instead of `src/assets/img` and then use `/img/${this.filename}`